# .htaccess rediraction pattern issue

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have set of files i would like to redirect to another set of files

Example list of files and redirection files

```
http://www.example.com/test-1-constant/   >  http://www.example.com/test-constant-1/
http://www.example.com/test-2-constant/   >  http://www.example.com/test-constant-2/
http://www.example.com/test-3-constant/   >  http://www.example.com/test-constant-3/
```

I have this code that doesn't bring required results ( not fetching 1,2,3 beetween "-"

```
RewriteRule ^(test-)(.+)(-constant)$ /test-constant-$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?test-(\d+)-constant/?$ /test-constant-$1/ [NC,R=301]
```

You had an issue with the treatment of the trailing slash and the regular expression you used could be enhanced to be more precise.

That rul will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file). You should definitely prefer the firsts option if you can.

In your question you write about "files" targeted by those URLs. Above rule set takes that for granted. If those are actually (virtual) folders only, so if the actual URLs can be longer, then you need to modify the pattern slightly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?test-(\d+)-constant(/.*)$ /test-constant-$1$2 [NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for putting me in the right direction, your exact solution didn't  work but it works fine with a little change

Comment: RewriteRule ^test-(.*[a-zA-Z-])-constant/$ /test-constant-$1 [NC,R=301]

Comment: `(.*[a-zA-Z-])`? What is that meant to express? "Anything of any length followed by a letter or a dash"... I doubt that really is what you want to match... Maybe you want to tell us what sequence your file names can actually contain at that point.

Comment: yes, there are names between "dashes" of random lenght and on occasion include dash

Comment: That pattern matches _any_ string, as long as it ends with a letter or a dash.

Comment: well, this work for me well, but in the same time i just got into another problem, that i need to exlude on specific file from this redirection pattern, i will update this in the question

Comment: please don't take me wrong here but your code as you have in answer dosen't redirect on my server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187187/discussion-between-nita-and-arkascha).